# mysql trigger on a federated table

Tags: mysql, trigger, mysql-5.6, federated-table

I have two MySQL(5.6) databases `D1` and `D2` on two different machines.
There is a table `T1` on `D1` and there are two tables `T2A` and `T2B` on `D2`.
I want to update `T2B` whenever `T1` is updated.

`T2A` is a federated table and `T1` is base table of it.
There is an "`After Update`" trigger on `D2` which updates `T2B` whenever `T2A` is updated.

When there is an update on `T2A`, `T2B` table is updated by trigger.
When there is an update on `T1`, `T2A` table is updated by federation **but the trigger to update `T2B` as well is not triggered**.

So when there is an update on `T1`, `T2B` table is not updated automatically, only `T2A` is.
How to solve this?

Comment: For the future, when you ask a question that gets no response and you want to address it at a different community, you can flag it for migration, no need to cross-post.

Comment: Related (perhaps not identical) questions: [Federated tables and triggers](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/42425/federated-tables-and-triggers) and [Create a trigger to update table data on another Server's database](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/44758/create-a-trigger-to-update-table-data-on-another-servers-database). There are more, under the **Related** tab, on the right `----------------> Related`

Comment: i think there should be a "federated-table" or "federated-storage-engine" tag here as in stackoverflow.com.

Comment: @tylerdurden now there is ;)

Answer (score 2):

Federated tables are not transactional by nature, so you don't want to put a trigger on it. Alternative would be to put a trigger to post to another local table. 
See: [Federated tables and triggers](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/42425/federated-tables-and-triggers)